# AngularJS: when to add promises to scope and when not to?

Tags: angularjs

What is the best practice when it comes to setting variables in the scope?

Right now I often mix modes :

```
$scope.foo = FooResource.get()

//OR
FooResource.get().$promise.then(function(foo){
  //load a bunch of other stuff on to foo etc..
  $scope.foo = foo;
});
```

This is starting to come back to bite me later when in my directives I 2-way bind to something that may have been set in scope as a promise which I need to resolve, or it comes in as undefined and I need to add a watch on it.

It seems that promises is the way to go, if so, what are some patterns for dealing with unresolved promises in the views?

Comment: An unresolved promise just doesn't set the model value - why is this a concern for the view? (and the first approach doesn't make sense at all - how is `foo`-as-a-promise usable in the view?)

Comment: you are right, updated first line. angular wants an object that has a $promise on it in order for it to work in the view.